# How do I make a column invisible in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I make a column invisible in a gridview? I tried to use this:

```
dataGridView.Columns(0).Visible = False
```

But its getting an error `"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"`. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the AutoGenerateColumns set to true? I think that auto-generated columns are not contained in the Columns collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.  Using this we can make a column invisible:

```
Private Sub dataGridView_RowDataBound( _
   ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs _
) Handles dataGridView.RowDataBound
   If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow OrElse _
      e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header OrElse _
      e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer _
   Then
      e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ouch, that is a painful way to do it... try getting the column in the PreRender event of your page and setting its visibility then.

Comment: do you need the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand why is not working with you.

Its working just find on me - at least on c#.

Check to see what is going wrong, maybe you call it before the DataGrid is rendered/created or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement "dataGridView.Columns(0).Visible = False" was ok, you just need to fix the index. The Columns and Cell indexes are base 1, not base 0.

If you want to make invisible the first column use:

dataGridView.Columns(1).Visible = False

That works for me.